# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\pap\confirme.php on line 18

Tags: php, authentication

After the user types in the Username and Password it's checked if it's a valid user and a valid password. But I keep getting this error when I try loging-in.

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "localhost";
$password = "123456789";
$dbname = "escuteiros_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT ID, Utilizador, Password FROM criancas";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       if ($_POST['username'] == $row["Utilizador"] && $_POST['password'] == $row["Password"]) {
                $_SESSION['Utilizador'] = $_POST['username'];
                header("Location: Homepage.php");
       }
       if ($_SESSION['Utilizador'] == "Administrador"){

                header("Location: HomepageAdmin.php");

    }else{
           $message = "Username and/or Password incorrect.\\nTry again.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    header("Location: Homepage.php");
        }
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `if(!$result) { echo $conn->error; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to do with the fact that $result is not an object.

You have

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

After that $result is not an object. To check, do as AbraCadaver suggested after that line and check if $result is actually an object.

```
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if(!$result) {
     echo $conn->error;
  }

  if($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        //your code here
  }
```

Comment: I thank you both for your help. The problem has been solved and I feel a bit stupid for no noticin gwhat it was earlier.